# PHP Regular Expression ignoring special characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

With the help of SO, I was able to make a regular expression for my purposes, it works great, but it completely ignores special characters.

```
$pattern='/(?=.*\b\Q'.str_replace(' ','\E\b)(?=.*\b\Q',$requestedservice).'\E\b)/i';  
preg_match($pattern, $item)
```

Here `$requestedservice` is the character that it's trying to match with `$item` from the database.

The `$item` is `Walk - Dance` so if the `$requestedservice` is `Walk - Dance` as well, it's not matched, but if the `$requestedservice` is `Walk Dance` it is matched.

I am not sure  why it's ignoring special characters like `-` `/` `%`

I am using `html_entity_decode` for the `$requestedservice` so that's not an issue.

Any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: The reason is that adding word boundaries around all non-space chunks is not a good idea as the non-word chunks will only be matched when enclosed with word chars. What are your actual requirements? If your input is `Walk - Dance`, do you need to check for `-` or not?

Comment: Yes, I need to check for `-` as well

Comment: show sample input and $requestedservice that are not working for you

Comment: Use https://ideone.com/CVyIKR

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It matches all special characters, except for `&`

Comment: @Cowgirl *That* works in all cases, your problem is with `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your word boundaries are working against you.  If you have `.`, for instance, your pattern is `/(?=.*\b\Q.\E\b)/i`, which asserts that there is a literal `.` with a word boundary before and after it, and since `.` is a non-word character, that means there has to be a word character before and after it.

Instead you could use `(?<!\w)` in place of the first and third `\b` and `(?!\w)` in place of the second and fourth `\b` to specifically assert there is not a word character before and after each of your string parts that need to match.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I am able to match `-` character. But the `&` character does not want to match at all. It matches all other charecters like `.` but does not match `&`

Comment: @Cowgirl what string with & are you trying to match, and what is the `$requestedservice` ?

Comment: The string is `Walk & Dance` and the `$requestedservice` is `Walk & Dance` it cannot match `&` for some reason

Comment: @Cowgirl are you certain the string or requestedservice isn't actually `Walk &amp; Dance`?  There's nothing this regex would be doing differently with `&` so your data is not what you think it is.